# Problem renaming files in a NTFS partition

Tags: windows, filesystem, ntfs

I have one partition with Ubuntu and one partition with Windows XP, I have also another NTFS Partition where I share my files.
I ve had many times the problem when I use Ubuntu and rename a file located in the NTFS partition, then when I want to use it in windows it appears with no icon and it says "windows cannot read the source file or disc", I can´t even delete it.

regards,
Victor.

---

I noted that the names of the files were ending with a space so I think Windows dont like it. I renamed it in Ubuntu and now I can access them.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, and how do you mount the Windows system?

Comment: any restricted words or special characters in filenames?

Comment: correct shutdown ?

Answer (score 2):

Linux uses some characters witch are not recognised in Windows for file names. Check the encoding for ntfs in Ubuntu and set it to utf8 using the tool pysdm. Pysdm configures for mounting at startup. Just deselect the partitions in pysdm to avoid mounting them at startup.